# gRPC "certificate verify failed" - C# Server and C++ Client

Tags: c#, c++, ssl, openssl, grpc

I have a problem implementing SSL into my GRPC application.
The server is based on Unity/C# and the client connects from C++. Everything works well without the secure connection.
I assume I'm doing something wrong with the SSL keys I use.

This is the way I generated SSL keys (I used `localhost` as Common Name):

```sh
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out rootCA.key
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key rootCA.key -sha256 -days 3650 -out rootCA.crt
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out localhost.key
openssl req -new -key localhost.key -out localhost.csr
openssl x509 -req -in localhost.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out localhost.crt -days 3650 -sha256
```

My C# server code:

```
private void SetUpServer()
{
    var sslKey = KeyPem.text; // localhost.key file
    var sslCert = CertPem.text; // localhost.crt file
    _server = new Server(new List<ChannelOption>
    {
        new ChannelOption(ChannelOptions.MaxSendMessageLength, MaxMessageSize),
        new ChannelOption(ChannelOptions.MaxReceiveMessageLength, MaxMessageSize)
    })
    {
        Services =
        {
            VertexStream.BindService(new VertexStreamServerImpl(VertexService, exampleVertices, exampleTriangles)),
            RobotData.BindService(new RobotDataServerImpl(RobotService))
        },
        Ports = {new ServerPort(Ip, Port, new SslServerCredentials(new List<KeyCertificatePair> {new KeyCertificatePair(sslCert, sslKey)}))},
    };
    _server.Start();
}
```

My C++ client code:

```
auto ssl_options = grpc::SslCredentialsOptions();
ssl_options.pem_cert_chain = "[localhost.crt content]";
ssl_options.pem_private_key = "[localhost.key content]";
ssl_options.pem_root_certs = "[rootCA.crt content]";
auto channel_creds = grpc::SslCredentials(ssl_options);
auto channel_arguments = grpc::ChannelArguments();
channel_arguments.SetMaxReceiveMessageSize(MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE);
channel_arguments.SetMaxSendMessageSize(MAX_MESSAGE_SIZE);
const std::shared_ptr<Channel> &channel = CreateCustomChannel(IP ":" PORT, channel_creds, channel_arguments); //TODO define IP and port
VertexStreamingService vertexStreamingService(channel);
RobotDataService robotDataService(channel);
```

When I call the first remote function (ie. `robotDataService.requestInitialPosition()`) I get an error:

```
E0903 11:36:08.390065443  522774 ssl_transport_security.cc:1395] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.
E0903 11:36:18.383416475  522778 ssl_transport_security.cc:1395] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.
```

I have already tried several ways of generating and including the key/crt files but haven't been successful so far. I need the code to work on the local network without access to the global internet so I assume I can't use remote certificate authority.

Comment: Openssl is probably using TLS for authentication.  Five years ago the industry decided to eliminate TLS 1.0/1.1 and require TLS 1.2 (or later) due to security leaks in 1.0/1.1.  Microsoft in June pushed a security upgrade that disabled 1.0/1.1.  So older version of Openssl may not have the upgrades for TLS 1.2.  So first check your version of openssl to see if it supports TLS 1.2.

Comment: @jdweng My SSL version is `OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020` so it does support TLS 1.2

Comment: Try genpkey which replaces genrsa.  See : https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man1/openssl.html

Comment: Also see following which say to use =sigalgs for TLS 1.2 : https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/SSL_CONF_cmd.html

Comment: Ok, now I used genpkey. I updated the commands in the post. It still shows me the same error.
I think `sigalgs` is an argument for openssl client. I use openssl only to generate the keys.

Comment: I also noticed that the error stays the same if I leave `ssl_options` fields empty. So gRPC doesn't verify anything. Maybe I'm ussing wrong files there? It's the first time I use SSL/TLS.

Comment: The server is a slave and does what the client requests.  So if gRPC is setting wrong parameters you have to fix the gRPC.  The openSSL will only work if gRPC is a version that supports TLS 1.2.  I have seen recently where the gRPC was an old version that didn't support TLS 1.2.  So you may need to update gRPC.

Comment: I use a rolling release distribution and keep the system updated so all of the libraries should be up-to-date. My gRPC version is 1.30.

Comment: In client you need a statement like tlsVersions := []string{"SSL30", "TLS10", "TLS11"} (see https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/1917) using TLS12.  I looks like gRPC version 1.31 supports TLS 1.3.  So I assume the previous version 1.30 should support TLS 1.2 (not sure).  If you do not specify the TLS version normally most systems default to latest, but again not sure.